# How to use nix-build -E to build a package with overrides

Tags: nix

In particular, I'd like to do a build with `doCheck=true`.

As a starting point, when I try this with my package of interest (`singularity`):

```
nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -E '(import <nixpkgs>{}).singularity'
```

The end goal would be something like:

```
nix-build -E '(import <nixpkgs>{}).singularity.override { doCheck=true; }' --pure
```

Both of these result in the error message:

```
error: expression does not evaluate to a derivation (or a set or list of those)
```

Of course, maybe there is an easier way to enable `checkPhase` as well, in which case, I guess this question might have two answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error *expression does not evaluate to a derivation (or a set or list of those)* is caused by the `'<nixpkgs>'` in your command.

Getting rid of that gets past the error but your second example fails with *anonymous function at /nix/store/*-nixos-18.09pre142796.4b649a99d84/nixos/pkgs/applications/virtualization/singularity/default.nix:1:1 called with unexpected argument 'doCheck', at /nix/store/*-nixos-18.09pre142796.4b649a99d84/nixos/lib/customisation.nix:74:12*

That's because `override` allows you to amend the set which is passed to `callPackage` and that set does not have a `doCheck` attribute. `doCheck` is part of the set passed to `mkDerivation` and other equivalent functions. To change those attributes you need `overrideAttrs`:

```
 nix-build -E '(import <nixpkgs>{}).singularity.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: { doCheck=true; })' --pure
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `oldAttrs` so named?

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure it is running `checkPhase` for every dependency! which also requires every dependency to be built, either way a very long process. While not necessarily a bad thing every time, it is a bit excessive most of the time. Is there perhaps a way to only have `checkPhase` run for a single package (i.e. the top level expression being built)?

Comment: The function passed to `overrideAttrs` takes a single argument which in most examples is named `oldAttrs` because it's a set containing the original attribute values passed to `mkDerivation`. It allows you to use the original values in the decision-making process for determining the new attribute values. How odd that it's running the checkPhase for each dependency the documentation (https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-check-phase) doesn't suggest that behavior. I think that's a good question for the #nixos IRC channel on freenode.

Comment: I think I know the issue. I tried it again and the same didn't happen. I had also specified `-I nixpkgs=/my/local/nixpkgs`, which caused many packages to be built, and many of these probably had a default of `doCheck=true`.